# Best practice: handle class error

Tags: php

Is it at all possible to have a class return `false` instead of an object reference? It would make error handling very clean. Consider the code:

```
$page = new PageContent('www.google.com');
if ($page)
  // do stuff
else
  // handle error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. But you can `throw` an exception in the `__construct()` method, and handle that.

Comment: I agree. Use Exceptions for this. They are designed for it :).